# PHP preg_match/replace doesn't work on character "ndash" after file_get_contents

Tags: php, preg-replace, file-get-contents

I get a String via `file_get_contents($file)`.

Why can't I replace a "–" (not "minus" but HTML `&ndash;`) with PHP's preg_replace function? preg_match also doesn't work:

e.g.

The output of the `$file` is "blah – blah".

`$str = file_get_contents($file);
$str = preg_replace('/–/', 'test', $str);
echo $str;`

should return `blah test blah` but returns `blah – blah`.

Whey is that and how can I replace a ndash instead?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `'/\p{Pd}/u'` first. If it does not work, it is probable that the symbol is present  in the string as an entity and you need to run `preg_replace` before converting the symbol into an entity, or you need to use `html_entity_decode` before replacing. E.g. `preg_replace('/–/', 'test', html_entity_decode($str))`

Comment: I have absolutely no issue with that (apart from your obvious syntax error in your fist code line). Most likely you did not overload your preg functions to operate in multibyte mode.

Comment: I tried your code using an online php editor, and it worked fine http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e5bbced117493fc6a9282444197360a1ae75dde

Comment: You have not provided all the relevant code in the question, it is off-topic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `preg_replace('/–/', 'test', html_entity_decode($str))` worked perfectly, thank you you're a life saver :)

Comment: Please add more details to the question, where the input comes from, or if you are encoding the input before the preg_replace.

Comment: So, the text in the file is actually `blah &ndash; blah`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the file contains an HTML entity for the long dash, and in order to get the plain text with `–` you need to  use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) first.

Use

```
$str = preg_replace('/–/', 'test', html_entity_decode($str));
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/NUEGHx):

```
$str = 'blah &ndash; blah';
echo "Original: " . $str . "\n";
$str = preg_replace('/–/', 'test', html_entity_decode($str));
echo "Replaced: " .  $str;
```

Output:

```
Original: blah &ndash; blah
Replaced: blah test blah
```